# Использование экземпляра класса без десериализации

Tags: c#, .net

Есть класс. Я сериализую его через `BinaryFormatter` в `FileStream`. Теперь вопрос, а можно ли использовать этот класс прямо из файла, не десериализуя его целиком в память (ну например класс весит 4 ГБ, согласитесь, это накладно)?

**UPD:**

> а как вы себе это представляли, без десериализации? Бинарная
>   сериализация вообще не предусматривает частичного разбора и чтения,
>   она не для этого. Для сложных кейсов обычно используют ORM и разные
>   классы с кучей полей и ленивой загрузкой

А это позволит мне работать именно с объектом типа `MyClass`?

Если честно, я слабо это представляю.

> Есть способ "unbox" из памяти, только надо ещё подумать как в память
>   загрузить обьект (точнее вычислить где он в памяти находится)... это
>   вы имеете ввиду? Как в с (с++) что б загрузить в структуру байты?

Мне не надо загружать объект в память. В память для передачи должен загружаться только член, который я запрашиваю

> 4 Gb - это не СУБД случайно))) В случае больших обьектов используют
>   Мемоry Mapping, но в таком случае обьект бьют на страницы, и работают
>   со страницей.

Чисто технически это не СУБД. А фактически - это огромный набор данных, хранящийся в экземпляре класса. Очень не хочется писать все это в реляционную БД, а с другими я не знаком. Очень сложно будет перевести схему класса в схему БД. Точнее не то что бы сложно, просто они будут сильно отличаться, а значит при расширении функционала придется решать немало задач совместимости, вместо того, чтобы уйти с головой в логику. Не люблю я переделывать схемы. Если она одна - это норм, но когда появляется другая, связанная с первой, но отличающимися возможностями, начинается головная боль.

**UPD2:**

Примерно так выглядит класс (не могу предоставить дословный код, но смысл будет понятен, думаю):

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    List<MyClass2>
    List<MyClass3>
    List<MyClass4>
    ...
}

[Serializable]
public class MyClass2
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
    public MyClass3 Prop3 { get; set; }
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: У вас что-то не так с дизайном. Класс должен представлять собой абстракцию сущности реального мира, и вряд ли такая сущность будет состоять из 4Г неделимых данных. Разбейте ваши данные на логические подобъекты и работайте с ними по отдельности.

Comment: @iRumba: Семантика ваших данных, вот чего мне не хватает. Потому что сериализация объекта размером в несколько гигабайт означает, что всё надо переписать по-новой скорее всего.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37098/discussion-on-question-by-irumba-----).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таких задач лучше использовать базу данных. 
Она именно для таких случаев и предназначена. :)

А для того что бы работать было удобно и как с обьектом нужного класса -- используй micro-ORM. Например PetaPoсo.

Десериализировать файл частично у тебя не выйдет.

В твоем случае возможно имеет смысл работать с SQLite бд, если не хочешь ставить себе SQL сервер. Хотя я не в курсе что у тебя там за данные и можно ли их хранить в SQLite. Просто предположение на основе уже имеющейся информации.

---

Так же полностью поддерживаю ВлаДа в его коментариях.

MyClass из твоего примера и является БД.

листы с MyClass2, MyClass3, MyClass4 -- явные БД таблицы.